# How to remove a background behind the image that i've added to a button

Tags: css, image, button, javafx, graphics

So i've created a button and used the  to have an image inside the button.

The image i'm providing has a transparent background but when I add it in as a graphic, the program adds a border around it as shown. The book is the iamge i'm providing.
[image: Book Icon]

Here's the source code on how i'm adding an image to a button in JavaFXML.

Firstly I defined the id

```
        <fx:define>
            <Image fx:id="ReadIcon" url="@Resources/MainIcons/ReadIcon.png" />
        </fx:define>
```

Then I actually add it to the button.

```
      <Button layoutX="363.0" layoutY="583.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleReadHemingwayButtonAction">
          <graphic>
              <ImageView image="$ReadIcon" />
          </graphic>
      </Button>
```

Just not sure how I can remove this border from the image.
Warm Regards

Comment: Is the border coming on the graphic or on the button?

Comment: Its on the button, I had made it transparent in photoshop beforehand

Comment: If it's on the button, I think you'll need to set it the border to 0px on the button for the desired effect.

Comment: Changing the border just removes the image

Comment: I might be wrong here as I do not use JAVA but for icons and button glyphs there is a rule that transparent color is located in one of the corners (IIRC top left) of the image itself.